# MEMORYCLERK_SQLOPTIMIZER in SQL 2012 Memory usage extremely high and causes server to crash

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, memory

I have been having issues with our SQL server for a while now.  It seems to run out of memory every few days and when I look at the memory dump, the `MEMORYCLERK_SQLOPTIMIZER` seem to take over memory and eventually cause the server to crash.

Here is the SQL version we are using:

> Microsoft SQL Server 2012 (SP1) - 11.0.3460.0 (X64)   Jul 22 2014
>   15:22:00      Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation     Enterprise Edition
>   (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.2  (Build 9200: ) (Hypervisor)

It is on a VM on Windows 2012 Server.

It has 20 GB of RAM allocated to it and the `Max Server Memory` is set to 16.5 GB.

I have seen the `MEMORYCLERK_SQLOPTIMIZER` grow to about 11 GB at the time of the server crash.

Does anyone know why that is happening?  What is causing the `MEMORYCLERK_SQLOPTIMIZER` to get so high?

I have looked it up and it looks like it has to do with ad-hoc requests, but is there something I can do to bring that memory down when it gets so high so that I can prevent a server crash?

Do we just need to add more memory or is there a memory leak somewhere?

I have already enabled `optimize for adhoc` and that does not seem to help.  We will be deploying SP2 soon. We are  using VMWare 5.1 and we are not using dynamic memory.

Comment: Can you post the info of `dbcc memorystatus`? Also, are stats and index up-to-date and not fragmented respectively?

Comment: I can't paste the memorystatus, it's too long.

Comment: `701 errors are key thing that you described`. Check this [KB - SQL Server 2012 experiences out-of-memory errors](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2769594) - which is fixed in 2012SP1-CU2. You can post the dbcc memorystatus on pastebin.com